# Hiding document sets based on field value

Tags: permissions, document, audience-targeting

I have a large document set library (+ 4.000 folders). When a new document set is created the users define a department, which this document set belongs to (HR, IT etc.) 
The problem right now is that all users have access to each others folders. I want to make the folders visible based on which department the users belong to, so e.g. a user from HR don't see the folders from IT. 
We discussed setting item level permissions (and running a workflow sorting this out), but item level permissions will slow down the system and is not recommended by most experts.

We have SharePoint groups that define the correct roles. Is it somehow possible to make documents sets visible based on field value (department) and a SharePoint group?

Something like:
if user == member of HR SP Group 
show all document sets where field value IT == HR
OR
if user == member of IT SP Group
show all document sets where field value department == IT
OR
etc.

Comment: One easy wayof doing it would be a document library per department and give the department group unique permission on the library level.. but it might be hard to move everything and keep everything intact.